# is it possible to limit the message size of linux

Tags: centos, logs

I am now using centos 7, I found the `/var/log/messages` too large. is it possible to limit the size of message? This is the message size:

```
[root@k8smasterone log]# duc ls -Fg /var/log
  1.1G messages-20221125             [++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]
  1.1G messages-20221126             [++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++      ]
619.5M messages                      [+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                                                                   ]
389.0M pods/                         [+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                                                                                               ]
 86.9M sa/                           [++++++++++                                                                                                                                    ]
 60.0M journal/                      [+++++++                                                                                                                                       ]
 35.4M audit/                        [++++                                                                                                                                          ]
 31.5M calico/                       [+++                                                                                                                                           ]
  1.2M dnf.librepo.log-20221030      [                                                                                                                                              ]
  1.2M dnf.librepo.log-20221113      [                                                                                                                                              ]
  1.2M dnf.librepo.log-20221120      [                                                                                                                                              ]
  1.2M dnf.librepo.log-20221106      [                                                                                                                                              ]
  1.2M dnf.librepo.log               [
```

Comment: That's a log file. It seems as if there is log file rotation in place, rotating the file every day. The size of the file would depend on the amount of logging happening.  If you look in the file (`less /var/log/messages`), is there any particular log entries that you notice there being an excessive amount of (like disk issues or some service running with debugging turned on)?

Comment: I append some schedule task log into the message file, it it possible to limit the size of the file automatically? @Kusalananda

Answer (score 1):

`logrotate`, at least on opensuse, will rotate, compress and delete old log files, using certain rules. You can configure how big the raw log file can get before renaming and compression, what compression to use, and how many of those old compressed log files are kept before discarding.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to rotating the logs, it may be helpful to actually look inside the log and figure out why it is so big.  Presuming rotation is working, perhaps there is a broken service that needs to be disabled, repaired, or needs its debug messages turned off.

Alternately, syslog rules can be added to filter out the offending noise maker to its own file, or drop some or all of its content completely.   If you move it to its own log file, you could also set up a faster log rotation schedule for it.  Something this large will probably compress quite well.